# Формула увеличивающая отличия чисел?

Tags: математика

Скажем есть числа 48 и 52.
Если их представить графически в виде столбца, то будет казаться что
половинки одного размера. А нужно графически показать что отличия более  явные, чем на 4. Но пропорционально, чтобы сумма чисел осталось той же.

Как это можно сделать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

Похожий вопрос, но с дополнительными условиями
[Формула для увеличения отличия чисел с сохранением позиций других элементов?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/898030/%D0%A4%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%83%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB-%D1%81-%D1%81%D0%BE%D1%85%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%85-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: "Но пропорционально" - пропорционально чему?

Comment: Отличие от 50% - один столбик вообще пойдет вверх, другой вниз...

Comment: как вариант, можно просто подкрасить разность другим оттенком... или, если различия всегда небольшие, отображать в экспоненциальной шкале...

Comment: Ну сумма чисел не должна меняться. Скажем 48+52=100. 
Скажем 40+60=100. 
То есть 48 превратиться в 40, а 52 в 60.

Comment: Это же дело наглядности именно. На мой взгляд нужно выбрать более подходящий формат для графического изображения отличия двух чисел: два столбца рядом, круговая диаграмма и т.п.

Comment: Нет, формат именно такой нужен. Я помню несколько лет назад такую же задачу решал и там была формула для этого.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`0.5` и `25` - параметры масштабирования, которые Вы можете настраивать на Ваш вкус.

```js
function rescale(tuple) {
  if (tuple.min > 25) {
      tuple.min = (tuple.min - 25) * 0.5 + 25;
  }
  tuple.max = 100 - tuple.min;
  return tuple;
}

for (var i = 1; i <= 49; i++) {
  console.log(i, JSON.stringify(rescale({ min: i, max: 100 - i })));
}
```

Comment: А min это что? Меньшее из чисел?

Comment: А если сумма чисел отличается от 100? Как задать параметры масштабирования в зависимости от значений?

Comment: @manking пропорционально

Answer (score 7):

Берёшь любую возрастающую функцию, симметричную относительно 50 и применяешь.

```js
function scale(x, p) {
  return (50 + Math.sign(x-50) * Math.pow(Math.abs(x-50), p) / Math.pow(50, p) * 50);
}

document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('input', function (e) {
  var x = +e.target.value
  
  for (var div of document.querySelectorAll('div')) {
    div.style.height = scale(x, div.dataset.p) + '%'
  }
})
```

```css
section {
  height: 100px;
  width: 32px;
  position: relative;
  background: blue;
  float: left;
  margin-right: 8px;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: red;
}

input {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input type=number min=0 max=100 autofocus value=0>

<section><div data-p=1></div></section>
<section><div data-p=.5></div></section>
<section><div data-p=.25></div></section>
<section><div data-p=.125></div></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Степенная функция с показателем степени b, где 0 < b < 1 подойдет.
Пусть х - размер меньшего столбца, а большего y = 100 - x,

```
x' = 50 - 50 * ((50 - x) / 50) ^ b,
y' = 50 + 50 * ((y - 50) / 50) ^ b = 100 - x',
```

где х' и у' - соответственно размеры меньшего и большего столбца после преобразования.

Например, если b = 0.5, и x = 49, то:

```
x' = 50 - 50 * ((50 - 49) / 50) ^ 0.5 ≈ 42.93
```

Comment: О, почти как у меня, только ты возведение в степень за скобки вынес. Ну и отрицательное число в такую степень не возводят.

Comment: @Qwertiy Тут уточняется, что х - высота меньшего столбца, так что отрицательным число в скобках быть не может. А так да - то же самое, что и у тебя.

Comment: Хм.. Да, не обратил внимания. Впрочем, тогда рисовать будет сложнее.