# Формула для увеличения отличия чисел с сохранением позиций других элементов?

Tags: javascript, математика, масштабирование

Нужно увеличить различия двух столбиков, при этом,сохранив позицию текста.

Дано:
A = 52, B = 48, C = 104.
Это высота элементов.

Нужно маштабировать элементы A и B на коэффициент Q, чтобы визуально они сильно отличались, сохранив позиции точки C.

То есть A2 может быть равно 74, B2 = 51, а С2 = 130. В итоге визуально, A2 будет казаться больше B2, а С2 будет располагаться над B2.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
С помощью какой формулы этого можно добиться?

---

В том вопросе важно чтобы высота столбца сохранилась. А в этом наоборот, нужно масштабировать весь столбец. Чтобы показать разницу между высотой столбцов 100 и 101.3. То есть нужно масштабировать и A и B, плюс внутри столбца так же отмаштабировать соотношение между A и B, плюс иметь возможность пропорционально сдвинуть координаты точки С, на то месте где они были.
A + B может быть равно 107 или 92. Это не число 100.

Comment: Чем плохи варианты в прошлом вопросе?  Тот же https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/897417/243285 достаточно умножить все связанные числа с диапазоном (100, 25) на Q и получится то же самое, но чуть больше

Comment: Хорошо бы подробнее расписать что за 100 и 25 коэффициенты. А то до конца не понятно как это применять. Скажем если входные значения A=80, B=60, то тут уже не нужно сильно искажать данные.

Comment: Ну в том примере диапазон равен 100, представление процентов, а для увеличения видимой разницы берется одна четвертая от него, 25. Точнее даже получается, что мы решаем, что хотим уменьшить значение, если оно больше чем одна четверть от нашего диапазона(25), если меньне - то не изменяем. С другими числами просто меняется диапазон, фактически их сумма 80 и 60 - 140.  Чтобы отмасштабировать его достаточно умножить все три числа на нужный множитель.

Comment: В том вопросе важно чтобы высота столбца сохранилась. А в этом наоборот, нужно масштабировать весь столбец. Чтобы показать разницу между высотой столбцов 100 и 101.3. То есть нужно масштабировать и A и B, плюс внутри столбца так же отмаштабировать соотношение между A и B, плюс иметь возможность пропорционально сдвинуть координаты точки С, на то месте где они были.